# Nativescript - onesignal failed to find module: nativescript-onesignal relative to app/tns_modules/

Tags: nativescript

I really don´t know where to search anymore, i see a lot of related problems but i seem to resolve one problem and then another one appears. The thing is, i´m using onesignal(with nativescript sdk) to send push notifications, and on ios everything works well, but then when i try to run locally on my android, many problems appear:

**First problem** was i was getting a maven **{ url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }** so i followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/roblav96/nativescript-onesignal/pull/41) and i mannage to get rid of that problem.Also i think is important to say that i´m using sidekick and from here i installed the onesignal plugin which points to [here](https://github.com/roblav96/nativescript-onesignal) but in those instructions(in the previous link i gave) points to another plugin...ok...no problem, i followed the rest of the instructions and now my **Second problem** is that the app IS installed on the run, but it breaks and shows the error that you see on the log below:

```
System.err: Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "nativescript-onesignal", relative to: app/tns_modules/
System.err:     com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:146)
System.err:     com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:55)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:553)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:545)
System.err:     com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
System.err:     android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1017)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4864)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:178)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1531)
System.err:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
System.err:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
System.err: File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/pt.wemakeapps.brleads/files/app/app.js', line: 8, column: 22
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err: Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "nativescript-onesignal", relative to: app/tns_modules/
System.err:     com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:146)
System.err:     com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:55)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:553)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:545)
System.err:     com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
System.err:     android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1017)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4864)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:178)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1531)
System.err:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
System.err:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
System.err: File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/pt.wemakeapps.brleads/files/app/app.js', line: 8, column: 22
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4867)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:178)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1531)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
System.err: Error calling module function
System.err: Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "nativescript-onesignal", relative to: app/tns_modules/
System.err:     com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:146)
System.err:     com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:55)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:553)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:545)
System.err:     com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
System.err:     android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1017)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4864)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:178)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1531)
System.err:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
System.err:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
System.err: File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/pt.wemakeapps.brleads/files/app/app.js', line: 8, column: 22
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err: Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "nativescript-onesignal", relative to: app/tns_modules/
System.err:     com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:146)
System.err:     com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:55)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:553)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:545)
System.err:     com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
System.err:     android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1017)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4864)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:178)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1531)
System.err:     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
System.err:     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
System.err:     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
System.err:     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
System.err: File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/pt.wemakeapps.brleads/files/app/app.js', line: 8, column: 22
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:553)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:545)
System.err:     at com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1017)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4864)
```

So, what is the problem? any thoughts?

Thanks for your time
Regards

Comment: Please paste the complete error log instead of attaching screenshots.

Comment: done!....i have edit my question..thanks for answering by the way

Comment: Looks like the plugin was not copied in the build, did you try a clean build after installing the plugin?

Comment: yes...i did what´s on the fir link i gave, after the title "Upgrading from 1.0.8" https://github.com/roblav96/nativescript-onesignal/pull/41

Comment: It says to do a clean build and then add the plugin

Comment: Manoj do you know if i need to had the android plataform in onesignal account also?

Comment: Yes, you you will have to configure android in onesignal account but this crash is at least not about that. It's with your source code only. The pull request you pointed seems to be required only for `tns build`? Does the original plugin works with `tns run` still?

Comment: Hi manoj, i did what you told me...install the plugin and THEN do a clean( i was always doing the other way around) and now it´s working, i mean...the app opens, but....it´s not asking to accept push notifications...something is missing

Comment: Are you calling `startInit` as in [docs](https://github.com/roblav96/nativescript-onesignal#android-1)

Comment: Hi Manoj, thanks for helping me...i had to create the android plataform in the onesignal account, that´s what was missing. regards